# How to get customer custom multi select attribute value in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, multiselect-attribute

I have created a customer multi-selected attribute but I am not able to get its value on checkout can you please guide me on how can I get it. I try these two solutions but it not work.

```
$customer = $customerSession->getCustomer(); 
echo $customer->getResource()->getAttribute('payment_method')->getFrontend()->getValue($customer);
```

2nd

```
$customer = $customerSession->getCustomer();
$paymentValue = $customer->getCustomAttributeText('payment_method')->getValue();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use CustomerRepositoryInterface as below

```
protected $customerSession;

protected $customerRepositoryInterface;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
) {
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
}

public function getCustomer() {
    if($this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId()){
        $customer = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId());
    }else{
        $customer = null;
    }
    return $customer;
}

public function getCustomerPaymentMethod() {
    if($this->getCustomer() != null){
        $customer = $this->getCustomer();
        if(!empty($customer->getCustomAttribute('payment_method'))){
            $customerPaymentMethod = $customer->getCustomAttribute('payment_method')->getValue();
            // use explode if it is saved as comma separated in DB
            // $customerPaymentMethod = explode(',',$customerPaymentMethod);
        }else{
            $customerPaymentMethod = null;
        }
    }else{
        $customerPaymentMethod = null;
    }

    return $customerPaymentMethod;
}
```